# Toggle between fullscreen editor and terminal in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, powershell-core

As a Windows systems admin, I use PowerShell quite a lot. With the release of PS Core, and the implication that the ISE is dead, I've started to try to use VS Code as my day to day tool. One feature I'm missing from ISE is the ability to swap between the editor and the terminal in fullscreen. I usually kept ISE open and maximized, and used Ctrl+R to swap between editor and terminal as needed. I haven't found a way to maximize the terminal, and swap easily between terminal and editor. I know I can make the terminal take up most of the screen, but a) this still leaves about 2 lines of editor open at the top, and b) there doesn't seem to be an easy way to then maximize the editor. Is there a way to minic the ISE behaviour that I haven't found yet?

Comment: Three and a half years later and I'm still getting +1's on this. :-) I would like to mention, however, that I don't do this anymore; since I'm writting system admin scripts, it seems to me that as a security best practice, I run VS Code as my day-to-day (non-admin) user, and run a separate PowerShell console as my admin account on my second monitor to run and test my scripts, as well as test out cmdlets to put into the script. I can't use the integrated debugger this way, but I honestly haven't needed it.  FWIW and YMMV and all that, of course.

Comment: similar question: [In VS Code, how can I toggle maximization of the current workbench part / editor group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58885067/11107541)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

To toggle between a full screen editor and a nearly full screen terminal you can use:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+m",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel"
}
```

with your keybinding of choice to replace the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> : that is mine.  You just need to "maximize" the terminal first - pull it up as far as it goes.  It will remember that between sessions.

---

**Revisiting this** :

As of v1.38 this is now pretty simple.  There are two commands that will toggle the panel/editors to full screen.

Pick some keybinding to use for the toggle trigger:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+q",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel",
    // "command": "workbench.action.toggleEditorVisibility"  either one
    "when": "!terminalFocus"
},
```

The above will expand the panel or editor to full height, but toggling back will return the panel to its original size but not to nothing.  If you want the terminal to bounce between full open and full closed try both of these keybindings:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+t",  // you could use     "key": "ctrl+`",  if you wish
  "command": "workbench.action.closePanel",
  // "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+t",
  "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel",
  "when": "!terminalFocus"
},
```

The order of the above 2 keybindings is **important**.

[image: toggle terminal demo]

---

v1.50 is adding the setting `panel.opensMaximized` - I tried its different options but couldn't get a simpler result than the two keybindings `ctrl+alt+t` version I showed above.  In any case, start with the panel closed for it to work well.

Comment: That's close; it bring the console to (mostly) maximized like you said.  However, when I toggle it again, the editor isn't maximized; I'm left with a half-half editor and console.

Comment: I think you just have to play with the initial positioning of the terminal - it works for me.  Set a starting position when "maximized" and another when almost closed and it seems to remember those positions - it's not perfect but pretty close to maximizing each in turn.

Comment: I had tried that, but I moved the bar all the way to the bottom.  I suppose that closed the bottom section, rather than actually moving the divider, because that's how I got the behaviour I mentioned. If I leave a line of console on the bottom, you're right, it does appear to be close to what I want. I'll leave this for a day or two, and if no-one gives me a better answer that's exactly what I want, I'll accept this one.

Comment: Whups, I spoke too soon.  If the focus is in the terminal, it doesn't work.  If the focus stays in the editor, the two swap as described.

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  ;>}   I see no difference in behavior depending on where focus starts.  I suppose you could make a macro to ensure focus shifts to the "maximized" panel. Or use another keystroke for terminal focus toggle.

Comment: Hrm, looks it's more the keybinding I'm using; I had replaced Ctrl + J in VSCode, but it seems there's a Ctrl + J binding in the PowerShell console itself getting in the way. If I change it to Ctrl + Alt + M like you have, it works fine. :-S I'm liking VS Code less and less; ISE seems to have been a better sysadmin tool. The console is such an afterthought in VS Code (not surprising, given VS Code's origins), it doesn't seem to be nearly as useful as the ISE console was.

Comment: Well, this looks to be the best answer I'm going to get.  I'll accept it on that basis.

Comment: Best alternative till microsoft decides to introduce this feature officially. Thank you.

Comment: This works for toggling between full screen terminal and closed terminal, but I am not sure how to automatically focus on editor window after I close the terminal. Anyone who knows how to do this?

  ```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "command": "workbench.action.togglePanel",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel",
    "when": "!terminalFocus"
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! In case of warning "`Maximizing the panel is only supported when it is center aligned.`", it should possible to set it to center via context menu on the panel tab section (e.g. on `Terminal` tab itself). Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77354988/5113030 , https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141094

Answer (score 38):

The below outlines my solution after reading @Mark 's answer, as it's slightly different. I use `ctrl-alt-m` to switch between a full-sized terminal and full-sized editor.

*note: this includes the mentioned integrated terminal and vscode application menu bars.*

For posterity's sake, I'm on vscode version 1.40.1.

### Implementation

You'll need to add to your keybindings within vscode and execute a manual step.

#### `keybindings.json`

Add this to your `keybindings.json` file, accessible via the [Keyboard Shortcuts editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings):

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+m",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel",
        "when": "!terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+`",
        "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal",
        "when": "!terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+m",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    }
```

#### Slide down the integrated terminal

Once you've done this and saved your `keybindings.json` file you need to *manually slide down the integrated terminal* all the way off the screen on the bottom, after opening from your editor with ctrl+`.

Afterwards, you should be able to use `ctrl+alt+m` in your editor and your terminal to get a full-screen-ish experience moving between them.

I've tested this on Ubuntu and Fedora locally as hosts and using remote-ssh to an Ubuntu remote from a Windows 10 host. This has the added benefit of allowing you to get the by-default smaller terminal from within your editor using ctrl+` but use a single command, `ctrl+alt+m`, for switching between editor/terminal. YMMV!

Comment: how to return the focus back to the editor after toggling the terminal?

Comment: @rahulKushwaha I just use the combo `ctrl+\``. That last character is a _backtick_, per the second `"key"` value, `"ctrl+\`"`, in the second block, above.

Comment: upvoted for mentioning where to actually put the change (keybindings.json)

Answer (score 18):

### Solution 1: Create Terminal in new Tab and Switch Between Tabs

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> > `Terminal: Create New Terminal in Editor Area` create a terminal as a new Tab (A.k.a. Editor). It looks like:

[image]

Now you can toggle between Tabs (A.k.a. Editors) and Terminal (Which is in a new Tab) using `View: Quick Open Previous Recently Used Editor in Group`

### Solution 2: Create Terminal in new Editor Group and Switch Between Editor Groups

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> > `Terminal: Create New Terminal in Editor Area to the Side` create a terminal in new Editor Groups. It looks like:

[image]

Now you can toggle between window and terminal using `View: Navigate Between Editor Groups`

### NOTE:

You can add keybinding to the commands as per your convenience. For example, in case of Solution 1:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+`",
    "command": "workbench.action.createTerminalEditor"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+tab",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup",
    "when": "!activeEditorGroupEmpty"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+w",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.killEditor",
    "when": "terminalEditorFocus && terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated && resourceScheme == 'vscode-terminal' || terminalEditorFocus && terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported && resourceScheme == 'vscode-terminal'"
}
```

Here, <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> are set by default. I just modified <kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd>.

The above keybinding will

- Create terminal when you press <kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd>
- Close terminal when you press <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>
- Toggle between fullscreen editor and terminal when you press <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>

Comment: Note that unlike the other answers, this method actually creates a terminal-as-editor which is not part of the panel. In particular this means you can have another part of the panel open while you use the terminal, although it also means there won't be a quick shortcut like `ctrl-\`` to get back to the terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure how that works. `Quick Switch Window...` moves me between VSCode windows (workspaces), not tabs within a window.

Comment: @BallpointBen Thank you very much for your feedback. I have updated the answer. Please let me know if you have any more issues.

Answer (score 12):

## Opening the terminal in VS Code in full screen

This solution will replace the standard keybindings in VS Code so the terminal toggles in full screen.

### Implementation

Open command palette `ctrl+shift+p` and search for `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` and paste this between the square brackets.

```
{ "key":"ctrl+j", "command":"workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel","when":"!terminalFocus" },
{ "key": "ctrl+oem_3", "command":"workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel", "when":"!terminalFocus" }
```

Comment: For peeps on macOS the "key" section should be "cmd+j"

Answer (score 8):

There is now an extension for exactly this. It is the "maximizeterminal" extension by Samuel T Scott. It redefines ctrl+` for opening terminal full-screen. The above keybinding methods, are also great, but in my experience they tend to not work properly once you start opening files by using cli like "code app.js". While using the extension such problems do not occur.

Answer (score 5):

For macOS users, you can set the shortcut in the same `keybindings.json` file.

- You can access the file using the shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, then write/select `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`.
- In `keybindings.json`, paste the following code between the square brackets:

  ```json
  { "key": "cmd+alt+m",
     "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel",
     "when": "!terminalFocus" }
  ```

You can change the shortcut to whatever suits you (mind rewriting any of the default ones!), but I set mine to the same as others suggested (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>) to keep a "standard".

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the terminal instance name at the top as seen below and then select "move terminal into editor area". This will allow you to have a full workspace view within VS Code.

[Image of process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX1Ni.png)

Answer (score 2):

I love this question, I believe I figured out something or at least got the behavior I was looking for.

Using the workspace setting here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107624

(enter ctrl+, and search "openmaximized" and set the dropdown to "always")

From there I set the keyboard shortcut for "Toggle Terminal" to ctrl+j (or whatever you may prefer) and now when I toggle my terminal it goes from full screen to toggled off

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 1):

⇧+⌘+↩ (Shift + Command + Return) toggles maximised terminal in Version: 1.81.1 (Universal) on MacOS.

Other useful default keybindings:

- ⌘+J toggles panel visibility, i.e. show/hide terminal
- ⌘+B toggles left side bar visibility

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Code, you can toggle between minimizing and maximizing the terminal window using the following shortcuts:

Windows/Linux: `Ctrl + (backtick)`

I also found `Ctrl + j` works

Answer (score -3):

For MacOS I found useful <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>