# In VS Code, how can I toggle maximization of the current workbench part / editor group?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to define a **single** and **universal** keyboard binding that allows me to **toggle** the **maximization** of the **current** workbench part, *regardless* of the type of part.

At a minimum, this would include the following parts **could** be:

- Any **single** editor group
- The **panel** itself

By **maximization**, note that I mean in both **height** and **width** so that the window takes over the full application window with the **exception** of the **side bar** (i.e. if the side bar is already visible, it remains visible at all times).

By toggling I mean of course going back and forth between the original **layout** (i.e. remembering it), and the maximization result.

---

**My thinking about this problem**

There are several command IDs that I believe could help here but none of them seem to do what I want, e.g.

- `workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths`
- `workbench.action.maximizeEditor`
- `workbench.action.toggleMaximizePanel`
- `workbench.action.toggleEditorVisibility`

I suspect that

1. there are more commands that could help here
2. there is probably a way to accomplish this with the right boolean logic of **when** clauses and joint execution of command IDs (?)

[image: Dow]

Comment: When you say `toggle` the panel for instance, typically that means it goes between full height and its previous partial height.  Is that what you want, or toggle between full height and zero height?  And same for editor toggle?

Comment: Thanks @Mark I'll clarify. I mean switching back and forth between its current height and width, and **full** **width** and **height** (keeping the *activity bar* or even the *side bar* is fine). I'll update this in the post to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect specifically to toggle maximize the current editor group, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53926099/836330 and the new command it mentions:

```
"View: Toggle Maximize Editor Group
```

---

Try this in your keybindings.json (chose your desired keybinding):

```
 {
    "key": "alt+m",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+m",
    "command": "workbench.action.closePanel",
    "when": "editorFocus && panelIsOpen"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+m",
    "command": "workbench.action.togglePanel",
    "when": "editorFocus && !panelIsOpen"
  },
```

It works well - has no effect on the SideBar or ActivityBar - except for one thing.  The `workbench.action.togglePanel` command in the third keybinding will appear to toggle the maximized editor but that command shifts focus to the opened panel.  Which might not be what your expect.

If you don't want that focus shift to the panel when un-maximizing the editor I think you will have to add a macro to the mix.  Disable the second and third keybindings and add this to your settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.toggleEditorWthFocus",
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.action.togglePanel",
      "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
      "workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths"  // will toggle other editor groups width
        // but other editor group width goes to a built-in minimum, not 0
    ]
  }
],
```

using the [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) macro extension.

and use these as your two keybindings:

```
  {
    "key": "alt+m",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },

  //{
  //  "key": "alt+m",
  //  "command": "workbench.action.closePanel",
  //  "when": "editorFocus && panelIsOpen"
  //},
  // {
  //   "key": "alt+m",
  //   "command": "workbench.action.togglePanel",
  //   "when": "editorFocus && !panelIsOpen"
  // },


{
  "key": "alt+m",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.toggleEditorWthFocus" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !panelIsOpen"
},
```

[image: toggle views demo]

I know you said you want the SideBar unchanged, but if you go the macro route I think it would be pretty easy to toggle that as well.

The comments above note that if you have more than one editor group, unfocused editor groups' width will be minimized, but it goes to some built-in minimum and not to 0 width.  I don't think there is a way to toggle other editor groups on/off other than by closing other editor groups which can be done but you probably don't want that.

Demo with split:

[image: toggle views with split]

Comment: This looks very promising @mark! I will give this a try soon and let you know with anything.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code doesn't come with such a feature. Though there is an issue ticket about it: [Maximize Workbench Editor #196722](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196722), which at the time of this writing is placed in the November 2023 milestone. You can show your support by giving it a thumbs up. You can subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump".

As for working around the current limitation, I think the trickiest part of attempting to work around something like this with keyboard shortcuts is there's no mechanism to remember what was open before maximizing something and minimizing those other things away (such as the primary sidebar, secondary/auxiliary sidebar, and the panel area). Ex. when you unmaximize, how would you know whether to open up the secondary/auxiliary sidebar again? You could create shortcuts that just assume that you have some "normal" non-maximized combination of things that should be open when nothing else is maximized, but I'm going to try a hacky way using zen-mode, which does have such memories, and which hides sidebars.

Limitations (sorry that there are a lot. It might feel like I'm not getting much farther than the asker's attempt, but part of what I'm trying to also do here is give a better/deeper idea of what the limitations are so the reader is not left completely in the dark as to what can or can't be done):

- This solution relies on [the maximization capabilities of VS Code 1.84](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77356279/11107541), so if you're on an older version, you'll have to upgrade or find another way.
- At the time of this writing, as far as I know, there's still no way to maximize the primary sidebar or the secondary/auxiliary sidebar. See also [Keyboard shortcut for making VS Code Explorer or other Views fullscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76681921/11107541).
- Since this is a Zen Mode approach, the Zen Mode settings apply, including: `zenMode.hideLineNumbers`, `zenMode.hideStatusBar`, `zenMode.showTabs` (used to be `zenMode.hideTabs` pre-VS Code 1.84), and `zenMode.centerLayout`. You might also be interested in [How to hide the VS Code bar with file name, breadcrumbs, and action buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74272910/11107541). I'm not aware of these toggles having commands that can be bound to keyboard shortcuts.

I used <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> because that's what I always use for random temporary stuff I'm trying. Replace it with whatever you want the key to be. Put this in your keybindings.json (open with `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the command palette):

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+b", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.maximizeEditorGroup",
            "workbench.action.toggleZenMode",
        ],
    },
    "when": "(editorFocus || inSettingsEditor || inKeybindings) && !maximizedEditorGroup && !inZenMode"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+b", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.unmaximizeEditorGroup",
            "workbench.action.exitZenMode",
        ],
    },
    "when": "maximizedEditorGroup && inZenMode"
},
{ // edge-case thing. edit to your taste.
    "key": "ctrl+b", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            // "workbench.action.maximizeEditorGroup",
            "workbench.action.exitZenMode",
        ],
    },
    "when": "editorFocus && !maximizedEditorGroup && inZenMode"
},
{ // edge-case thing. edit to your taste.
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.maximizeEditorGroup",
            // "workbench.action.toggleZenMode",
        ],
    },
    "when": "editorFocus && maximizedEditorGroup && !inZenMode"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+b", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.toggleZenMode",
            "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel",
        ]
    },
    "when": "panelFocus && !inZenMode",
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+b", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.exitZenMode",
            // "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel", // apparently not needed :/
        ],
    },
    "when": "panelFocus && inZenMode",
},
```

You may or may not need to put `"runCommands"` in your `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` setting.

---

There's also the fact that the VS Code team is experimenting with the feature to have open editors in separate windows (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77232931/11107541)), so perhaps you might find that satisfactory as a workaround (enable the experiment, drag editor to its own window, and fullscreen it).