# Is there a keycommand to toggle maximal editor space in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for something that basically combines cmd+B (show/hide sidebar) and cmd+J (show/hide terminal).

I've tried searching around but everything seems like there's only one per. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I temporarily maximize an editor group in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53925724/how-can-i-temporarily-maximize-an-editor-group-in-vs-code)

Comment: i already selected an answer (below)

Comment: oh actually I might have meant to point to [In VS Code, how can I toggle maximization of the current workbench part / editor group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58885067/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ I assume you know about zen mode but are looking for something different. ]

I think the easiest way to do this is with a macro extension, here using [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).

Put this into your keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "alt+u",                // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.maximizeEditor",
            "workbench.action.closePanel"
        ]
    },
    "when": "panelVisible && sideBarVisible"
},
{
    "key": "alt+u",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
            "workbench.action.togglePanel",
            "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
        ]
    },
    "when": "!panelVisible && !sideBarVisible"
},
{
    "key": "alt+u",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
        ]
    },
    "when": "!panelVisible && sideBarVisible"
},
{
    "key": "alt+u",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.togglePanel",
            "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
        ]
    },
    "when": "panelVisible && !sideBarVisible"
}
```

I made it, by using the `when` clauses, to be a toggle.  So the same keybinding would close both the sideBar and Panel if they are open or open them both if they are both closed.

Then I added the last two cases where one or the other of the sideBar or Panel is closed but not both.  You may not care about those two cases.

By the way, this will maximize the current editor group if there are multiple groups.

Comment: Perfect! Yeah - mentally, never been a fan of full screen takeovers on Mac.