# Keyboard shortcut for making VS Code Explorer or other Views fullscreen?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

We can toggle the VS Code Explorer's visibility with <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.  Is there a way to toggle it so it becomes full screen using a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know at the time of this writing, no, there is not. There's a command `View: Toggle Maximized Panel`, but there is no corresponding command for Views (things in the primary sidebar).

This was raised in multiple issue tickets (google "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues toggle maximized sidebar OR view feature-request`")

- [Allow to maximize Side Bar
  #95139](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95139) was closed as "by-design", but I think that was a side effect of the specific nature of the particular issue there (the issue raiser had moved a panel into the primary sidebar (view) area and was asking how to maximize that)
- [Command for maximize secondary sidebar (and sidebar)
  #152575](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152575) was [closed for not receiving enough community support in time to get added to the backlog](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152575#issuecomment-1221456753).

If you really want the feature, what I suggest that you do get it in the backlog is [raise it again as a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md), and then promote your feature request to your friends, colleagues, and on [r/vscode](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode), telling people to give the issue ticket a thumbs up if they would like the feature-request to get added to the backlog.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.