# Maximize terminal in VSCode when in side panel

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

In previous versions of VSCode there was an arrow icon at the top of the panel that could be used to maximize the panel, for instance the terminal. I do not know exactly in which version but that button is now gone and I'm unable to find an equivalent.

My question is: how can I maximize the terminal so it takes the whole VSCode window? Is there any way to get the button back?

Comment: If you keep your terminal maximized (press the '^' button once so it covers entire screen),you can use `ctrl+j` to show/hide terminal. I find this method quite pleasing because it is so fast to switch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Which version of VSCode are you using, and in which OS?

On Mac, and with 1.65.2 (the most recent update by now), I have it in the right corner, near the `X` button:
[image: Example expand terminal button]

### Shortcuts

Now talking about shortcuts to make your life easier, there are 2 you should be aware of.
PS: Remember that to change any shortcuts, just go over VSCode Command Palette and type `Keyboard Shortcuts` to change them.

#### Maximise panel size

There are no default shortcuts for those, in both Windows and Mac.
If you want to set any, the name of the shortcut is `View: Toggle Maximized Panel`:
[image: Toggle Maximized Panel shortcut]

#### Increasing / decreasing terminal size

Now talking shortcuts, if you want to resize your terminal window, in Mac there's a native shortcut that allows to increase / decrease terminal size with `Cmd + Ctrl` + `Arrow Up / Arrow Down`.
There's no default for Windows.
If you want to set / change those shortcuts, they are called `Terminal: Resize Terminal Down` and `Terminal: Resize Terminal Up`:
[image: Resize terminal shortcuts]

#### Terminal panel on the side

If you added your panel to either left or right, then the mark to make it fullscreen changes.
After clicking on the arrow below, it'll hide all your files and make the terminal to run in the whole screen for VSCode:
[image: Fullscreen with terminal at the side]

Comment: I'm on Windows, same version as yours. After your answer, I think I discovered a weird bug/feature: if the terminal is in the bottom panel I get the icon. To move the panel right (I usually have it this way, hence the confussion) there are to options (from the context menu):
 - "Move views to side panel"
 - "Move panel right"

They both accomplish apprently the same thing but with the first option the buttom to maximize disappears! I'm not sure about the difference between the two but I was using the first one and thus losing the ability to maximize the side panel.

Comment: It makes sense! The fact you're using the side panel, means it'll open full available space, anyways, right?
Glad to help

Comment: If you open as a side panel it does not open to fill the whole window, whatever that means. Even if you dont have the editor open it seems that the "Welcome window" is always there. You can make the panel bigger but never fullscreen, or at least I did not found a way

Comment: @skd what you could do is make VSCode go full screen after adding the terminal panel to the left (or right) is to use the same arrow, but now it'll change direction, and when clicked, will hide your other files. 
I've added this to the answer.

Comment: Given that for macOS the default to resize is `Cmd + Ctrl + Arrow Up / Arrow Down`, a pretty useful keybinding to `workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel` may be `Cmd + Ctrl + Enter`

Answer (score 6):

To get the `maximize arrow` on the left panel...

[image]

Left-click the bottom panel, then choose `Move Panel Left`

[image]

To get the `maximize arrow` on the bottom panel...

[image]

First, press the `Customize Layout` button

[image]

And select `Center` Panel Alignment

[image]

Then move the panel back to the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! As of 2023-03-10, this only works here.  Version 1.76.1

Answer (score 5):

I also got the arrow disappeared, but i manage to bring it back by with `command:workbench.action.alignPanelCenter`
But i don't know i un align it in the first place

So maybe it will work with you

Comment: As per https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144688

Answer (score 1):

Panel can be maximized when centered.
Example: If panel is not centered and the Maximize button is missing you also cannot use the command by hitting

`Shift-Ctrl-P` `View: Toggle Maximize Panel`

Fix: run these commands (press `Shift-Ctrl-P` then begin typing)

1. **First** command will enable the maximize button

`View: Set Panel alignment to Center`

2. **Second** command will now work to Maximize (or just press the button that shows up now)

`View: Toggle Maximize Panel`

Blue and skube have the right answer to the original question. I cannot comment so summarize an answer using commands that can be pasted to verify.

Answer (score 0):

In version `1.83.1` (`2023-10-10`), it is also possible via context menu on tab section in the panel. For example:

[image: 1]